# How to subset NetCDF in a remote server and scp the subset file into a local server

Tags: python, ssh, netcdf

There is a netcdf file is in a remote server. What i want to do is that extracting data/cropping the file (need only specific variable for specific period) and then moving the file into my local directory.

With python, I ve used 'paramiko' module to access the remote server; is there any way to use 'Dataset' command to open the netcdf file after ssh.connect? Or any solution with python is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: not by python modules/functions, just by executing a 'common' netcdf function to extract subset files on a remote server command line (i.e. myssh.exec_command("ncea -v %s %s %s" %(varname, remoteDBpath, remotesubsetpath) and them bring the files into a local server (i.e. myftp.get(remotesubsetpath, localsubsetpath).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [pydap](http://www.pydap.org/client.html). Once connected to the remote server, you can access the data subset as you would in numpy, e.g. `temp_slice = temp[0,1,0]`, and the data for the corresponding subset will be downloaded on the fly from the server.

Comment: It seems like the pydap is to access data on the internet when the url is known, but not possible to access another linux servers..?